# Selenium: unable to switch window

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I am trying to switch to another pop-up window,but is giving some sort of error. I am not able to figure out why the code in not working for switching the window

Error it is giving is

*java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: name=null*

Here is the code....

```
String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("parentWindowHandle......"+parentWindowHandle);
        //click on "register"

        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            act.click(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnRegisterMe")));
        act.perform();

        sleep(26000); 
        String popUpWindowHandle=null;
        Set<String> openWindowsList = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String windowHandle : openWindowsList) {
             System.out.println("windowHandle......"+windowHandle);
            if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandle))
                {popUpWindowHandle = windowHandle;

              break;}
        }                                                
                // Switching control to newly opened window

        driver.switchTo().window(popUpWindowHandle);
```

Comment: your issue is coming from `windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandle)`.  My guess is that `parentWindowHandle` is not initialized.

Comment: ya i hv initialize parentWindowHandle, but forgot to put that code here.have a look at the code which i hv reposted....

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to print window handles then try

```
if (!windowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindowHandle)){
            popUpWindowHandle = windowHandle;
            break;
}
```

instead of

```
if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandle)){}
```

Comment: thanx 4 the help .... its working with if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandle)){}

Comment: Can you share what was the actual problem and what you did to fix?

Comment: i have increased the sleep time from 5sc to 26sc......actually the problem was window switch code was executing before opening of new pop-up window....